# How can I convert an async iterator to an array?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Given I have an async generator:

```
async function* generateItems() {
    // ...
}
```

What's the simplest way to iterate all the results into an array? I've tried the following:

```
// This does not work
const allItems = Array.from(generateItems());
```

```
// This works but is verbose
const allItems = [];
for await (const item of generateItems()) {
    allItems.push(item);
}
```

(I know this is potentially bad practice in a Production app, but it's handy for prototyping.)

Comment: *This works but is verbose* Don't think you can get any better than that, since every item needs to be `await`ed individually in order to get access to the next Promise

Comment: `allItems = await generateItems().toArray()` is [currently proposed](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers)

Comment: There’s a new [`Array.asyncFrom`](//github.com/js-choi/proposal-array-async-from) proposal that mentions this post.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Looks like the [`async-iterator-to-array`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-iterator-to-array) npm library does this:

> Install
>
> ```
> npm install --save async-iterator-to-array
> ```
>
> Usage
>
> ```
> const toArray = require('async-iterator-to-array')
>
> async function * iterator (values) {
>   for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
>     yield values[i]
>   }
> }
>
> const arr = await toArray(iterator([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
>
> console.info(arr) // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
> ```

Comment: Note that referenced package does it internally exactly the same way which OP marked as "verbose". Think of it, do you really need another dependency in your project?...

Comment: @1valdis Note that this answer is written by OP.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a simple function to convert async iterator to an array without having to include a whole package.

```
async function toArray(asyncIterator){ 
    const arr=[]; 
    for await(const i of asyncIterator) arr.push(i); 
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: good one, same as implemented in accepted answer [see on GitHub](https://github.com/achingbrain/it-all/blob/3cb51331b0025832ea4571ba62f315c1c744b2b5/packages/it-all/index.js)

Comment: Thanks for this, surprised to learn that it isn't a first-order concept...

Answer (score 16):

If someone is still looking for a solution for this, as from ES22, you can use the new `Array.fromAsync()` static method.

this will return a promise whose fulfillment value is a new Array instance.

example from [ES propsal](https://www.proposals.es/proposals/Array.fromAsync):

```
async function* f() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) yield i;
}

// Resolves to [0, 1, 2, 3].
await Array.fromAsync(f());
```

*note:
browser compatibility isn't that great at the moment...

refrences:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fromAsync)
[TC39](https://tc39.es/proposal-array-from-async/#sec-array.fromAsync)

Comment: If anyone comes looking for the same information as me: this is not yet support in the latest Node as of writing, but is supported in Bun.

Answer (score 13):

Your solution is the only one I know of. Here it is as a TypeScript function:

```
async function gen2array<T>(gen: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<T[]> {
    const out: T[] = []
    for await(const x of gen) {
        out.push(x)
    }
    return out
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAnmYBJKBTATnARgGwxgF4YBvAKBhgG0BlRAW1xHwDoFk1McoQsAugAoAlOSrUYWDFACuWMOMmSAlgC4YABgA0E5WAwAPKKKXLVAMxhCoACxUQ2KmAB4YAZjGVz56XIUwAApYIIwOGGzSEKwAbhhCZDAxcPiyGBp2Dk4A1NnaMAAm4OkwFikQRAC+IgDceuaVFPXKfvKKwaHhkRjR+HEJhcUZWGn5yaklYLL4+DDVdT6NypULcxQrTaCQsBCEGAAOJNaMEGpTzNhixAB8MAYA7kEhYRVCWCS3FVAAKiqMGCBZCYsNoTiIRE1OChSrIUFAVOAAFTwJAoADiGAMvH4pm8kkQKgw+AKHlW1AJRJJABYyfB7nAVDs9vshABGTQQ5QU4kwACsdUaFChwBhcIRigA5piAExwLA4RAub7XIRSsAaACCqO42DwhCV1xEGg6LwwSpoAlueOoW2gMEBUA03wtRwt9Qs-DpDJMttghntVjVXmakgdbH2sggtiEhk5kiWklaAQd6yaQu1ouA8PAMEw0FxEltrAi+BAEqEcHpjJgatl8rgiAr2vQuoIGHBhfAvRLZYrVdgtblCqbXAxWLgfCwog7jTzJlqQA)

Comment: do you have any idea why this has to be type-hinted for `AsyncGenerator<T>` specifically? I wanted a more general function that accepts `AsyncIterator<T>`, which is the base-type of `AsyncGenerator<T>` - but for some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: @mindplay.dk I think it works with `AsyncIterable` but not `AsyncIterator`. I added a TS Playground link -- does that do what you want?

Comment: aha! yes, that works - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Typescript version of OPs verbose workaround, just to make it even more verbose and useful.

```js
async fromAsync<T as any>(source: Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<T[]> {
  const items:T[] = [];
  for await (const item:T of source) {
    items.push(item);
  }
  return items
}
```

## Usage

```js
const items = await fromAsync(generateItems())
```

Comment: Why duplicate [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63497965/735926) from three years before?